# Repeating Date Sequence Excel

Tags: excel, date

Using formulas and not VBA i would like to repeat a series of dates as many times as necessary. An example of my required output is below however the length of the sequence of dates and the date values are forever changing. Does anyone have any ideas? What i need is when the sequence hits the max value of the sequence to go to the start of the sequence and start again.

```
28/12/2015  1
04/01/2016  1
11/01/2016  1
18/01/2016  1
25/01/2016  1
01/02/2016  1
08/02/2016  1
28/12/2015  2
04/01/2016  2
11/01/2016  2
18/01/2016  2
25/01/2016  2
01/02/2016  2
08/02/2016  2
```

I'd really appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Where do you get the dates that need to repeat? And the number of times they need to repeat? You give very little detail to allow someone to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help! I have actually come up with a solution all be it quite long! Just to add a little more context: the dates are user entries which include a start date and end date. I have a formula that prints all of the dates of the week starts (starting on a monday) in the date range. So for example: start date is 01.01.2016 end date is 31.01.2016, the week starts are :
28/12/2015
04/01/2016
11/01/2016
18/01/2016
25/01/2016

Then i took the week number of these dates - 1 as Week 0 started in December. so i now have a series that looks like this:

0   28/12/2015
1   04/01/2016
2   11/01/2016
3   18/01/2016
4   25/01/2016

I created an additional column where the first row (A2) is equal to 0, and then used the formula: =if(A2 = count(WeekNum),0,A2+1).

This produced my looping weeknumbers and finally i did a vlookup on the weeknumbers to get my looping dates.

I hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

You have a starting date and want to add 7 days per row until you hit a max date?  Put the max date in a cell (A1), the starting date in a cell (A3), then in A4 enter:

```
=IF(A3+7>=$A$1,$A$3,A3+7)
```

Then copy this cell (A4) down as far as needed.